# Spring boot, GET API doesn't return new POST entries without restarting the micro-service

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jhipster

it has been two days trying to solve this issue. I'll try to explain it as detailed as possible.

I'm working on a spring boot micro-service (Jhipster)
I generated the following model, my intention was to get the whole JSON (tree) when calling api/configs

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF6GR.png)

My issue (as tested on POSTMAN) :
When running a GET request of api/configs, I do get the whole JSON (tree)

Then I add some entries (TitleConfig or SumConfig) using a POST request. api/title-configs AND api/sum-configs. => the data is saved to the Database (PostgreSQL)

I re run my GET request of api/configs, I don't get the new entries that i just added (POST request)

At the same time, a GET request of api/title-configs OR api/sum-configs, does return the new entries

Once I restart the micro-service (mvnw), my GET request (api/configs) does get those new entries.

The Parent GET API (api/configs), does not get the updated Data only if restart the micro-service.

Here is my ConfigDTO :

```
public class ConfigDTO implements Serializable {
    
    private Long id;

    private String code;

    private String description;

    private Boolean status;

    private Set<TitleConfigDTO> TitleConfigsDTO = new HashSet<>();

    private Set<SLADTO> SLASDTO = new HashSet<>() ;

    private Set<SumConfigDTO> SumConfigsDTO = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<TitleConfigDTO> getTitleConfigsDTO() {
        return TitleConfigsDTO;
    }

    public void setTitleConfigsDTO(Set<TitleConfigDTO> TitleConfigsDTO) {
        this.TitleConfigsDTO = TitleConfigsDTO;
    }

    public Set<SLADTO> getSLASDTO() {
        return SLASDTO;
    }

    public void setSLASDTO(Set<SLADTO> SLASDTO) {
        this.SLASDTO = SLASDTO;
    } ..........
```

Below is my api/configs

```
@GetMapping("/configs")
public Page<ConfigDTO> getAllConfigs(Pageable pageable) {
    Page<ConfigDTO> page = configService.findAll(pageable);
    return page;
}
```

Below the service

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<ConfigDTO> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return configRepository.findAll(pageable).map(configMapper::toDto);
    }
```

Below the mapper

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {SumConfigMapper.class, TitleConfigMapper.class, SumConfigMapper.class})
public interface ConfigMapper extends EntityMapper<ConfigDTO, Config> {


    @Mapping(target = "TitleConfigs", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "removeTitleConfig", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "SumConfigs", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "removeSumConfig", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "SLAS", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "removeSLA", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "Headers", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "removeHeader", ignore = true)
    Config toEntity(ConfigDTO ConfigDTO);


    @Mapping(source = "SumConfigs", target = "SumConfigsDTO")
    @Mapping(source = "TitleConfigs", target = "TitleConfigsDTO")
    @Mapping(source = "SLAS", target = "SLASDTO")
    ConfigDTO toDto(Config Config);

    default Config fromId(Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Config Config = new Config();
        Config.setId(id);
        return Config;
    } }
```

Thank you

---

First Try : added @EntityGraph (Does not work)

```
/**
* A Config.
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "config")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)

@NamedEntityGraph(name = "config_graph", attributeNodes =                     
@NamedAttributeNode(value = "TitleConfigs"))
@NamedEntityGraph(
name = "title_sum_config_graph",
attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "TitleConfigs", subgraph = "subgraph.TitleConfigs"),
subgraphs = {
@NamedSubgraph(name = "subgraph.TitleConfigs",
attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "SumConfigs", subgraph = "subgraph.SumConfigs")),
@NamedSubgraph(name = "subgraph.SumConfigs",
attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "Categories"))
})

public class Config implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "code")
private String code;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "status")
private Boolean status;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Config", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
private Set < TitleConfig > TitleConfigs = new HashSet < > ();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Config", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
private Set < SumConfig > SumConfigs = new HashSet < > ();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Config", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
private Set < SLA > SLAS = new HashSet < > ();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Config", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
private Set < Header > Headers = new HashSet < > ();
```

Comment: and we are supposed to guess what those controller methods do? YOu haven't included them so this would be impossible to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your time, I just added the controller methods

Comment: You seem to have 2 issues: seeing new entries (1) and getting full JSON tree (2).
1. Did you enable show_sql in hibernate properties to check which SQL queries are executed. It could be a caching issue. 
2. One-to-many relationships are lazy loaded by default, you may want to change it for your query by using `@EntityGraph` for example, here also SQL may show it in logs.

Comment: Thank you @GaëlMarziou for your reply and your analysis.
I tried your proposition EntityGraph, but did not work, I think i misused it.

Comment: Configuring eager fetching on OneToMany is usually a bad idea, read Vlad Mihalcea articles if you want to know why. Are you beginning in Spring data jpa? You did not say whether you found something from show_sql logs